# Regression without linearity

Tags: regression

Given two independent, standard-normally distributed random variables $x,y\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1).$ I would like to do an univariate linear regression without intercept $Y = X \cdot \beta + \epsilon.$ R gives me as estimate $\beta = 0$

n <- 10000
   x <- rnorm(n)
   y <- rnorm(n)
   plot(x,y)[image]
   fit <- lm(y ~ 0 + x)
   summary(fit)

but I feel the problem is not well-defined and any $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ appears to minimize the expected least square error if you consider a rotation of the coordinate system. Any thoughts on why $\hat{y} = 0$ minimizes the least squares criterion and not $\hat{y} = \hat{\beta} \cdot x, \hat{\beta} \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Are you asking to fit the same model $Y=\beta \cdot X + \epsilon$ using a different minimization criterion?  From the picture, $\beta = 0$ seems plausible, because of the rough symmetry about the origin.

Comment: No, I am not interested in Laplacian, Huber, etc. criterion. Cost function is just standard expected least square criterion which should be minimized.

Comment: The data are rotation invariant but the cost function (and therefore the solution) is not.

Comment: I edited the question already to clarify it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @hardmath mentioned in the comment, the results are perfectly logical. If $Y$ and $X$ are independent and each one is $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, so clearly (from independence) $cov(X,Y)=0$ and the real intercept is $0$, because $(0,0)=(\mathbb{E}X, \mathbb{E}Y)$. Hence, the real regression line is simply $y=0+0 x+\epsilon=\epsilon$, where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ which coincides with the OLS results.

Answer (score 1):

If the regression data are symmetric with respect to changing the sign of $y$, the least-squares approximation is the line $y=0$.  The error is a sum of pairs $((y+a)^2 + (y-a)^2)$ all of which are minimized at $y=0$.

If the data are samples from a symmetric distribution then $y=0$ is the expected regression line and the actual line will be a small random perturbation of that.